# NServiceBus pub/sub and hardcoded publisher location

Tags: nservicebus

Is the a way to make a subscriber subcribe on a message type without knowing the publishers (location)? I guess this could be done with a central subscription storage.

Answer (score 2):

NServiceBus tries to gently guide you towards good SOA practices. One of these is that there can only be one logical publisher for each published message type.  (Although, that logical publisher may have multiple physical worker processes.)

Because of this, I'm not sure why you would want to subscribe to an event and *not* know where it is published from.

If you could explain a bit more about your particular use case, it might be helpful in determining what your true motivations are.

Comment: I just don't like that every subscriber should know the location of the publisher. What if I like to move the publisher to antoher server, or if I create antoher publisher sending the same event type? Then I have to find all subscribers and re-configure them.

Comment: It makes sense to not have to know the location of publisher. Is that not the purpose of SOA? Knowing or requiring to know the location of the publisher would mean you are coupled to the publisher endpoint/location. Refer to this article on location transparency, http://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-benefits-of-location-transparency-in-an-soa/1049544

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at the Distributor from NServiceBus.

http://www.nservicebus.com/Distributor.aspx

Normally the Distributor would be used for LoadBalancing. You subscribe regularly in your Distributor to the messages from your publisher but your Subscribers must only have to know the address of your Distributor.

Comment: This is *not* a recommended use for the Distributor.